# How can I pass my configuration class like @SpringBootTest(classes = "configclass".class) in @QuarkusTest?

Tags: quarkus

How can I pass my configuration class like

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = "configclass".class)
```

in @QuarkusTest?

Comment: There is no such feature in Quarkus. What is your use case?

Comment: I have to inject one customized Object mapper  from the config class  to my test class.In spring boot test  ,the bean from the config class is taken. But in Quarkus test , how can  we inject the bean from the config class

Comment: Does https://quarkus.io/blog/mocking/#old-approach suit your needs?

Comment: Hi @geoand thanks for your reply, but  exact use case is: I have a config class like below:                                                                                              ,,@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigClass {
    ,,@Produces
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        //some more configuration
        return mapper;
    }
}   If I use ,,@Inject
  ObjectMapper objectMapper;  in my test class it is not taking the above object mapper